# Need check if the existing session yii2

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I create the sessions with $key and IP. My doubt is about how to check if the session exists and how to update it.

This is the function that I use to check user access.

```
public function access(int $userId, Token $token, string $ip, string $userAgent): void
    {
        if ($this->sessions->hasForUserByIp($userId, $token->token, $ip)) {
            return;
        }

        $conn = $this->sessions->countForUser($userId, $token->token);

        if ($conn >= $token->max_conn) {
            throw new \DomainException('Sessions limit is reached.');
        }

        $session = Session::create(
            $userId,
            $token->token,
            $ip,
            $userAgent
        );
        $this->sessions->save($session);
    }
```

Sorry for the long explanation, I am learning and don't have much experience.

Answer (score 0):

This works, in case someone needs it

```
if ($this->sessions->hasForUserByIp($userId, $token->token, $ip)) {
            ($this->sessions->update($userId, $token->token, $ip));
            return;
        }
```

In repository

```
public function update(int $userId, string $key, string $ip): bool
    {
        return Session::updateAll([
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'key' => $key,
            'ip' => $ip,
        ]);
    }
```